# How to read values interms of milli(m), femto(f), micro(u) into float values

Tags: pgfmath, csv, pgfmathparse

I have a `.csv` file, which contains values interms of milli(m), femto(f) and micro(u)etc. which I want to process it as float value inside `pgfmathparse`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mycsv.csv}
Device, betaeff,    cbb,    cbd,    cbdbo,  cbg
nma,    384.242m,   10.1129f,   -371.143a,  -371.143a,  -16.1414f
nmb,    1.97148,    61.2938f,   -805.157a,  -805.157a,  -83.9924f
\end{filecontents*}
...
\begin{document}

...
\csvreader[head to column names, filter strcmp={\Device}{nma},]{mycsv.csv}{}{\betaeff}
```

I'm able to read `\betaeff` value as `384.242m`, but I want to process this data using `pgfmathparse`. But I couldn't able to process as a value.

Any suggestion as to how these values.

Comment: Let me ask the following question to make sure I fully understand the input structure of  your data. Are the units of the numbers in data column 1 not meter but millimeter; in data column 2 not Farad but femtoFarad; in data column 3 not Ampere but micro Ampere? What about data columns 4 and 5 -- are they as in data columns 3 and 2, resp.? Please advise.

Comment: Yes,, a denotes atto unit in Farad. These are data from a circuit simulator, which I want to process it inside Latex beamer for my presentation.

Comment: Please add a MWE to your question. PGFMath can't deal with values in the mikro, femto or atto magnitudes unless the `fpu` library is used. Do you really want to do scientific calculations inside TeX? You could declare `m`, `u`, `a` and `f` as postfix `\pgfmathdeclareoperator` though this is not a documented feature of PGFMath and might not work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `siunitx`? You could set the package to ignore certain tokens

```
\sisetup{input-ignore=afm}
```

and use either `\num{\betaeff}`, `\qty{\betaeff}{<unit-here>}`, or even `\tablenum{\betaeff}` (for tabulated data) to print a number.

Example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{mycsv.csv}
Device, betaeff,    cbb,    cbd,    cbdbo,  cbg
nma,    384.242m,   10.1129f,   -371.143a,  -371.143a,  -16.1414f
nmb,    1.97148,    61.2938f,   -805.157a,  -805.157a,  -83.9924f
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{input-ignore=afm}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
head to column names,
filter strcmp={\Device}{nma},
]{mycsv.csv}{}{\tablenum{\betaeff}}

\num{123.456m}
\end{document}
```

The idea is actually based on a code in section 5.4 of the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I never used this package.
But the solution only ignores the postfix unit, but couldn't treat as absolute value like `384.242X10^-3`.
I want to process this value inside `\pgfmathparse`.

Comment: It would work if your number was in following format `384.242E-3` but if you insist on PGF math, it's also possible but you will probably need to create a custom function for that.

Comment: Could you help me with that custom function?

Comment: I wish I could help but I'd rather avoid trying something I am not confident with. In [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), the page 1048 section 96 is all about what I mentioned. I think you are better off asking a new question and wait for someone much more experience at PGF than me. I am sure someone will answer your question.